# how to download page source info of a webpage in vb.net or perl

Tags: vb.net, winforms, perl, http, firefox

I want to download the same information which is obtained when we right click view page source in browser. I want to do this either in vb.net or perl

I need it for google image search result webpage.
When that page is saved then html code is not same as view page source info.
Tags for images are absent.

In vb.net I tried

```
     Dim objHttp As Object, strURL As String, strText As String

    objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

    strURL = "http://www.google.co.uk/images?as_q=aboriginal&hl=en&output=search&tbs=isch:1,iur:fmc&btnG=Google+Search&as_epq=&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_sitesearch=&safe=images&as_st=y&biw=1600&bih=799"

    objHttp.Open("GET", strURL, False)
    objHttp.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", _
      "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)", "Accept", "image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5")

    objHttp.Send("")

    strText = objHttp.responseText

    objHttp = Nothing

    RichTextBox1.Text = strText
```

Though above method gives the links to the search result image it does not return the image tags (by image tag i am referring to short sentence below every image in google image search).

Is there any way to get the whole view page source info in vb.net or perl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer at http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/internet/urldownloadtofile.htm

Answer (score 0):

I would try:

Turn off Javascript in your browser.   Now go and visit that Google Images search page (the one linked in your source code) - the url will change slightly.

I'm guessing that loading that slightly changed URL by vb will give you regular html and not a bunch of obfuscated javascript.